# failing to install sagemath on ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation, gnome-terminal, 18.04, sagemath

Recently, I have install Ubuntu 64amd making duak boot with Windows 7 32bit. Everything is ok ,but I'm unable to install sagemath in it. it says " unable to locate the package sagemath-upstream-binary" even when the code is correct. may I know why?

Here are the complete code I have used:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:aims/sagemath
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sagemath-upstream-binary
```

Below are the terminal codes:

```
kutubuddin@kutubuddin-h81m-s:~$ sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:aims/sagemath
[sudo] password for kutubuddin: 
Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aims/sagemath/ubuntu bionic InRelease           
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [69.9 kB]    
Err:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aims/sagemath/ubuntu bionic Release             
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.xx.xx xx]
Hit:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease             
Hit:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease           
Reading package lists... Done                                  
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/aims/sagemath/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
kutubuddin@kutubuddin-h81m-s:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aims/sagemath/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [69.9 kB]
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aims/sagemath/ubuntu bionic Release             
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.xx.xx.xx]
Get:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [65.4 kB]   
Hit:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease           
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/aims/sagemath/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
kutubuddin@kutubuddin-h81m-s:~$ sudo apt-get install sagemath-upstream-binary
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package sagemath-upstream-binary
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [PPA you mentioned](https://launchpad.net/~aims/+archive/ubuntu/sagemath) does not have packages for 18.04 LTS.

In case of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Bionic Beaver **you do not need any PPA** to install SageMath.

You can simply remove the PPA (if added before):

```
sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:aims/sagemath
```

and then install sagemath from repository:

```
sudo apt-get install sagemath
```

Comment: This does not work as of July 1, 2018. I get error `Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aims/sagemath/ubuntu bionic Release            
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/aims/sagemath/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file`

Comment: `UPDATE 2017: Sagemath is now in Debian and there is no longer a need to maintain this PPA.
Try the Sagemath in your distro or try download the compiled binaries from sagemath.org.`  lots of error trying your second command after the above. `E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/sagetex/python-sagetex_3.0+ds-6_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/sagetex/sagetex_3.0+ds-6_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com`

Comment: ^ "In case of 18.04 LTS **you do not need any PPA** to install SageMath." ^