# Problem arises after installing sagemath on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, sagemath

I have asked a question to install sagemath on ubuntu [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031170/failing-to-install-sagemath-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts). But After complete installation it says :

```
Package configuration


Postfix Configuration                                                             │ 
  │ Please select the mail server configuration type that best meets your     
  │ needs.                                                                    
  │                                                                           
  │  No configuration:                                                        
  │   Should be chosen to leave the current configuration unchanged.          
  │  Internet site:                                                           
  │   Mail is sent and received directly using SMTP.                          
  │  Internet with smarthost:                                                 
  │   Mail is received directly using SMTP or by running a utility such       
  │   as fetchmail. Outgoing mail is sent using a smarthost.                  
  │  Satellite system:                                                        
  │   All mail is sent to another machine, called a 'smarthost', for          
  │ delivery.                                                                 
  │  Local only:             
No configuration:                                                        
  │   Should be chosen to leave the current configuration unchanged.          
  │  Internet site:                                                           
  │   Mail is sent and received directly using SMTP.                          
  │  Internet with smarthost:                                                 
  │   Mail is received directly using SMTP or by running a utility such       
  │   as fetchmail. Outgoing mail is sent using a smarthost.                  
  │  Satellite system:                                                        
  │   All mail is sent to another machine, called a 'smarthost', for          
  │ delivery.                                                                 
  │  Local only:                                                              
  │   The only delivered mail is the mail for local users. There is no        
  │ network.                                                                  
  │                                                                           
  │                                 <Ok>
```

I don't know what is these? How can I get rid of this?

Comment: For anyone else who has this issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/87872/how-do-i-accept-the-configuration-screen-that-pops-up-when-installing-postfix

Answer (score 1):

Sagemath depends on Postfix. I have no idea why though. You cant get rid of the popup, but you could just select

> │  No configuration:
> │   Should be chosen to leave the current configuration unchanged.